# Overshoot of BJT circuit driving LEDs

Tags: bjt, led-driver, passive-filter

It's a BJT circuit driving LEDs with a constant current and I adjust the brightness of it by sending PWM into the base of BJT.

The problem is that I can see huge overshoot of LED current right after the base voltage is turned on.

Could you help me find a solution?

Where is the capacitor supposed to be placed? Vce? Vbe?

[image]

Comment: can you show the huge overshoot of current and how you measured it?

Comment: You should probably try low-pass filtering the PWM to avoid massive current peaks.

Comment: A capacitor parallel to the LED can help.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you show works as shown, and it draws roughly the LED current the formulas imply. But it wastes potentially quite a lot energy unnecessarily.

To convert PWM into a roughly constant current, use an inductor in series with the load, and a second switch - eg. a diode - to keep the inductor conducting at all times. The PWM frequency scales the current ripple amplitude when the inductance is held constant: the higher the frequency, the lower the ripple. For a fixed PWM frequency, the larger the inductor, the smaller the ripple.

A minimally wasteful PWM LED driver circuit would look as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2febRq1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 is a saturating switch. Q2 desaturates Q1 on turn-off, and improves performance when the duty cycles are small.

The current loop D1-L1-D2 should be kept small. C2 limits Q2's dV/dt and dI/dt on turn-on, and should be connected directly between the collector and emitter.

R1 and R2 are chosen to keep Q1 saturated, while consuming a reasonable current from the PWM GPIO pin.

The average LED current, given a PWM duty cycle between 0 (0%) and 1 (100%), is:

$$ I_{avg} = D.\!C. \frac{V^+ - V_{Df}}{R_L},$$

where \$V_{Df}\$ is the LED forward voltage - usually 1.5-2V, and \$R_L\$ is the DC resistance of the inductor. The inductor resistance is a trade-off between the reasonable duty cycle and losses.

A small 1mH inductor in a through-hole package that resembles a resistor would have about 10Ω series resistance.

For the 20% example, the average current would be a bit below 200mA.